# How to add ripple effect and have custom background on button in android?

Tags: android, xml

Please tell me how to achieve both these together, I have gone through many already questions, but they dont specifically deal with my issue.

I want to have ripple effect on my button as well as it should be rounded and have background color. Also I should be able to control ripple effect color.

I tried few things which are listed below.

First Method: I tried setting `style="@style/AppTheme"`in the `<Button>` tag. This gives me ripple effect and background color (using `<item name="colorButtonNormal">#500347</item>`in the style) but the button is not rounded.

So to achieve rounded shape I gave `android:background="@drawable/button_bg"` in the `<Button>` tag. This makes button rounded and also background color is achieved, But Ripple effect is gone.

Second Method: I tried the using selector.
 1. Created button_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg"/>

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ripple_effect"/>

    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ripple_effect"/>

</selector>
```

2. rounded background for button in button_bg.xml:

   ```
     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid
       android:color="#500347" />

   <corners
       android:radius="10dip" />

   <padding
       android:bottom="0dip"
       android:left="0dip"
       android:right="0dip"
       android:top="0dip" />
   ```
3. ripple_effet.xml:

   ```
       <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
      tools:targetApi="lollipop">


       <item android:id="@android:id/mask">

   <shape android:shape="rectangle">

       <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

       <corners android:radius="10dip" />

   </shape>
   ```

4. In `<Button>` tag 
   `android:background="@drawable/button_bg"`

With this method button just goes white when pressed returns to background color.

Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer here. https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/blob/master/README.md

But if there is any other easier way, more answers are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way :-

1. `android:background="@drawable/ad_action_view_bg"` to my view. // Background is a Ripple drawable
2. Then I set `android - foreground` to required color.